# Trying to write a function in MATLAB to play a song given a vector of notes (frequencies) and lengths

Tags: matlab, audio

I would like to be able to take two vectors as inputs to a function in MATLAB such that the first has all of the frequencies I would like to play, and the second has the corresponding duration of each note.  What I have so far is:

```
%% Initialize
clear; format short e;

%% Possible Notes
octave = [55 110 220 440 880];
for k = 1:length(octave)
    pause = 0;
    A(k) = octave(k);
    As(k) = octave(k).*2^(1/12);
    B(k) = octave(k).*2^(2/12);
    C(k) = octave(k).*2^(3/12);
    Cs(k) = octave(k).*2^(4/12);
    D(k) = octave(k).*2^(5/12);
    Ds(k) = octave(k).*2^(6/12);
    E(k) = octave(k).*2^(7/12);
    F(k) = octave(k).*2^(8/12);
    Fs(k) = octave(k).*2^(9/12);
    G(k) = octave(k).*2^(10/12);
    Gs(k) = octave(k).*2^(11/12);
end

%% Notes and Durations
Notes = [D(2) D(3) D(2) D(2) C(3) D(2) D(2) A(3) A(2) ...
         A(2) G(2) A(2) A(2) F(3) Fs(3) D(2)];
Times = [1/4  1/4  1/5  1/5  1/4  1/5   1/5 1/4  1/5 ...
         1/5  1/4  1/5  1/5  1/4  1/8   1/4];

%% Play the Song
playSong(Notes, Times);
```

I have in my 'playSong' function the following:

```
function [song] = playSong(freqs, times)
fs = 44600;
makeNote = @(freq, time) cos(2*pi*[1:time]/fs * freq);
song = []

%% For Loop
for k = 1:length(freqs)
    % make the song somehow
end

sound(song, fs)
end
```

I've been grinding over how to create my vector of sounds to be played, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.  Does anyone know how I might go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) You can use [`sound`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html) or [`soundsc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/soundsc.html) to convert your vector\matrix of signal data to sound.

(b) If you want to generate audio using the sound card **and** you have a 32-bit version of MATLAB and Data Acquisition Toolbox, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/examples/generation-of-audio-using-the-sound-card.html) an example how to use it.

(c) you can record audio to an audio object using [`audiorecorder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html), and then play it using ['audioplayer'](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioplayer.html)

You have several examples in all of these options on how to implement and play your notes.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much everything I need.